# Microsoft Active Directory and DNS on Multiple Sites

Tags: domain-name-system, active-directory, windows-server-2019, microsoft

I have a 3 different site location of my company, and i have a domain controller on each site,, and I have issue with domain DNS resolving , example ::

Domain Name = ABC.Local

Site1 : DC GC+DNS IP = 10.100.101.10
Site2 : DC GC+DNS IP = 10.100.102.10
Site3 : DC GC+DNS IP = 10.100.103.10

when some client pc from example site1 try to reach the domain controller the DNS resolve it to DC on different site example 10.100.102.10 which the client on the site1...

so this is very issue with me because maybe the other site is offline or unreachable by network,,,

I try to use a "Try next closest site GPO" but still have the same issue,,,

there is any idea for this problem???

Thanks

Comment: Do you have Active Directory Sites and Services set up with all of your sites and subnets?

Comment: yes, the sites and subnets on each site was configured

Answer (score 1):

DNS by default will return round-robin entries. This has nothing to do with how a Windows client natively locates a domain controller.

DNS will also return a local address if Netmask Ordering is enabled (default), and the client and DC are on the same 255.255.255.0 subnet. If Netmask Ordering is not applicable, you can use DNS policies to influence what records are returned for each location.

Finally, if you have DC's registering for the domain's same as parent record, and they aren't globally accessible, that is what should be fixed. DNS Mnemonics can be used to fix that.

https://dirteam.com/paul/2013/01/02/preventing-spoke-dc-s-from-advertising-in-the-hub-site-for-authentication-availability/